# (mongo) Arrays of ids : how should I do it?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, meteor

today I finished the functional part of my website, so I went into the secure-my-app part of development. I want to give to users only the content they are related to, so, to my teachers ( = a user with user.role == "teacher"), I only want to give them access to a given assignment if their _id is in the assignment.teachersList array of _ids. I want to make this verification in the publish so i MUST get a cursor in the end of the query.

After looking at the **[OFFICIAL documentation of mongo](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-arrays/)** , it seems like doing what I want should be as simple as :

```
// in a publish
Assignements.find({ teachersList: this.userId });
```

However, this always returns me false. First, being afraid of a **this** context problem, I tried something like :

```
// in a publish
let self = this;
Assignements.find({ teachersList: self.userId });
```

and it's not better, I still get nothing. I tried to use Cursor.map() and put my condition there, but as map doesnt return a cursor, I get the data but it's not working either since we are in a publish.

It's written in the doc that the first try I made should work, so no doubts I'm making something wrong, but what .. ? 
Right now i'm starting to wonder if the problem comes from the fact that it's an array of **_ids**. Right now, it's only an array of Strings. And it seems that **this.userId** in a method only returns a String.... But maybe i'm wrong and I should use **Meteor.Mongo.ObjectId(the_string_id)** objects instead?

Alright that's it ! Please, if you have any idea why such an easy query doesnt work, tell me ! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

teachersList is an array, and not an id. You are trying to find an document with an id that has the value of an array... not going to work...

I usually use this pattern on all private owner collections: add an onInsert event to my collection and then add the user as ownerId to the document being inserted. Then, when it comes to publish, I publish all documents with the ownerId of the user. Clean and simple, no roles even needed...

If, however you decide not to use the pattern above...

From [MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/):

`db.inventory.find( { tags: { $in: [ /^be/, /^st/ ] } } )`

This query selects all documents in the inventory collection where the tags field holds an array that contains at least one element that starts with either be or st.

In Meteor your query might look something like:

`Assignments.find({ownerId: { $in: teachersList}});`

Comment: Thanks for your answer as well, again, your pattern is quite a good idea ! You teached me something :) I'll probably use it in future project :)

Comment: I didn't come up with that pattern though, found it some time ago somewhere in  a tutorial, tried it and kept it...  if you are happy with the answer and it solves your problem, please mark it as an answer to avoid other people trying to answer it.